# data is not properly set in react and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting details from java API .I want to set some of the details to commonvo at UI side and send the
commonvo object to server side. I am using below code:

React component

```
import { getDetails, populateobjDetails } from './CommonAction'

     function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
            return {
                getDetails: (formType, commonVO) => dispatch(getDetails(formType, commonVO)),
                populateobjDetails: (obj, commonVO) => dispatch(populateobjDetails(obj, commonVO)) //edit 1
             }
        }
```

Redux Action:

```
export function getDetails(requestFormType, commonVO) {
    return (dispatch) => {

        axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/byName/${commonVO.name}`, { headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate,max-age=-1,private', 'Pragma':'no-cache' } }).then(
        (response) => {

                let obj= dispatch(setDetails(response.data[0]));
                dispatch(populateobjDetails(obj, commonVO))
                dispatch(setobjSearchLoadingFlag(false))
            }
        )
    }
}

export function populateobjDetails(obj, commonVO) {
    const objDetails = {
        projectAlias: obj.projectAlias,
        dateExpenseClose: obj.dateExpenseClosed,
        projectID: obj.projectId,
        id: obj.id,
        idClass: obj.idClass
    }
    return {
        type: POPULATE_OBJ_DETAILS,
        payload: { ...commonVO, ...objDetails }
    }
}
```

I am adding objDetails  in commonVO.But during "Submitting the form" for which these details have been set, i am not able to see new properties being set into the commonVO.

I am new to React-Redux and not much familiar with it.Please let me know if i need to do something more on Redux-react side?

Thank you

**Edit**: I added method 'populateobjDetails' in 'mapDispatchToProps' function (which was missing in code) and imported the method in the component

Answer (score 0):

Inside your redux action `getDetails` you're calling:

```
dispatch(populateobjDetails(obj, commonVO))
```

However, `obj` is not really defined inside that action anywhere, so an undefined object is being passed to `populateobjDetails`, that's why you're not seeing the new properties being set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Sorry I mistakenly typed wrong name here, i need to pass same object(in this case named as 'obj') to method 'populateobjDetails' which I am getting from API response. I have edited my question, Please check it once and let me know if you get it. Thanks a lot.